# How would I go about converting a PSM1 module to a PS1 script?

Tags: powershell

I'm pairing my Powershell module with Universal Automation to schedule jobs without using the task scheduler. However, it only accepts PS1 files. I can create a PS1 file and have it import the module, but how would I go about making it a valid PS1 file instead, so that I can use all of the features in UA?

Comment: What does "pairing" entail in this context? You want to bake Universal Automation into your own module? Or you just want to execute a function exported by the module as a scheduled job in UA?

Comment: With a few exceptions, there is no difference between ‘.psm1’, and ‘.ps1’ files. ‘.psm1’ of course uses Import-Module to get to all the goodies in the .psm1 ‘.ps1’, you just dot-source them to get at its goodies. .psm1 files has some other advantages over scripts, but they are not pertinent to your use case. So, as long as the module is just normal functions, then, just rename it and dot source it if needed. If it’s got other stuff, then make a copy of, rename the extension, and remove all the unneeded module specific stuff.